# How To Get the Original Size images From Gallery?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using following code to get the images loaded into a post gallery. this is working and returning images but all in small size `150 x 150 px`

Can you please let me know how I can modify the code to return the original size of the images in galley?

I have seen some post here at Stack Exchange but they all are dealing mostly with `thumbnails` not WordPress `Galley`

```
<?php
/* The loop */
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ( $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false ) ) :
        // Loop through all the image and output them one by one.
        foreach ( $gallery['src'] AS $src ) {
                    ?>                
                    <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="w-100" alt="Gallery image" />
            <?php
        }
    endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[get_post_gallery()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_gallery/) also returns `ids` of the images as string. So one way of doing it will be to explode those ids, loop through them and use [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) which accept any registered image size name, or an array of width and height values in pixels.

```
<?php 
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ( $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false ) ) :
      $ids = explode(',', $gallery['ids']);
            
      // Loop through all the ids and output image one by one.
      foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full');
        ?>                
          <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" class="w-100" alt="Gallery Image">
        <?php
      }
    endif;
  endwhile;
?>
```